# JavaFX: How to disable ScrollBars in TableView

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

I have a JavaFX `TableView` and I would like the table behavior to truncate the image of the `TableView` when the parent node resizes too small to display the data, instead of it becoming scrollable. To clarify, I just want the scroll bars disabled or not visible, so they don't show up.

Below is my node hierarchy in SceneBuilder in case that helps.

[image]

**Things I've tried below**

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713162/javafx-disable-horizontal-scrollbar-of-tableview), but the answer just makes the cells resize to fit the width, instead of disabling the `ScrollBar`. I read the documentation on `ScrollBar`s [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html), but I couldn't find a `visible` or `enabled` property. I also read the `TableView` documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) with no luck.

I searched the JavaFX CSS guide [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) and found that there are the two policies below that can refer to a scroll pane.

```
-fx-hbar-policy:
-fx-vbar-policy:
```

But wrapping the `TableView` in a `ScrollPane` did not work as expected. It did not allow me to "fit-to-parent". I would like to refer to these properties, but in a `TableView` directly if that's possible. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure on this, but could you use a `lookup()` on the `TableView` to access the `ScrollBar` directly? `ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) tableView.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");` and then disable it?

Comment: "_but I couldn't find a setVisible() or setEnabled() property_". `ScrollBar` inherits from `Node` which provides the `visible` and `disable` properties. And unfortunately the `ScrollBarPolicy` enum is specific to `ScrollPane` whereas controls like `TableView` have their `ScrollBar`s created as part of the `VirtualFlow`. As far as I know, there is no public API allowing one to configure the `ScrollBar`s of a `TableView` to never show.

Comment: @Zephyr I tried this, and I am able to apply .setDisable(true); to the scrollbar. However, that only makes the scrollbar gray out, and appear like a disabled button, but it is still visibly there and functioning. I am about to try setVisible, and some other things. I am just writing this to confirm that the lookup did work to a degree and communicate with you. Still trying to make this work myself in the mean time. Thank you for advancing me so far towards my goal.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you so much for the clear explanation. I am not terribly familiar with VirtualFlow, just now reading about it as I am still new to javafx, and I understand why I can't configure it directly. Your input is very useful, as always.

Comment: There's a feature request, [JDK-8090721](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090721), asking for a public/supported way to hide the scroll bars of a `TableView` but it hasn't been implemented as JavaFX 11.0.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hiding the scroll bars completely, whether they're "supposed" to be displayed or not, can be achieved with the following CSS:

```css
.table-view .scroll-bar * {
    -fx-min-width: 0;
    -fx-pref-width: 0;
    -fx-max-width: 0;

    -fx-min-height: 0;
    -fx-pref-height: 0;
    -fx-max-height: 0;
}
```

If you want to disable all scrolling then you can add an event filter to the `TableView`:

```
table.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, Event::consume);

// or if you only want to disable horizontal scrolling
table.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, event -> {
    if (event.getDeltaX() != 0) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

If you don't want the `TableView` to shrink when the parent gets too small, set the min size to use the pref size:

```
table.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

If you don't want the `TableView` to grow beyond its pref size, do the same with the max size. You can also give an explicit pref size if you want.

Comment: The comprehensiveness of this answer is fantastic, but I have one small question regarding the css. I have multiple tables, and I would like to scroll in the others. If I wanted to refer to just one TableView, and the css-id for it was firstTable, how would I do that? I tried preceding the block with ".firstTable", but there is clearly something I don't understand yet about javafx css beyond referring to certain id's. Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: If `"firstTable"` is the _id_ then you should use `#firstTable`. All together it'd look like `#firstTable .scroll-bar * { ... }`. JavaFX-CSS is [based on](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph) CSS 2.1 and some CSS 3, along with some custom features; the linked document provides links to the CSS reference pages.

Comment: You can also use `.table-view .scroll-bar * {-fx-min-width: 0; -fx-pref-width: 0; -fx-max-width: 0;}` to get only the vertical scroll bar, and vice versa for only the horizontal scroll bar. I know it's counterintuitive, but it won't work if you use it the other way. (P.S. I can't get the code formatting correct here in the comments; I suggested an edit to the answer for this but it was rejected.)